# Angular and API in same domain web.config

Tags: asp.net, angular, iis

I have typically two domains for my apps, one for the app and one for the api, like this
[www.app.com](http://www.app.com) <--- Angular running, web.config needs to rewrite everything to index.html
api.app.com <--- my api

Now I would like to save some ssl-costs and change the logic to this

[www.app.com](http://www.app.com) <--- the same
[www.app.com/api](http://www.app.com/api) <--- api now here

How do I need to change the web.config for this configuration to work? I'm struggling with the route rules

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="API Routes" ...>
          <match url="...">
        </rule>
        <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: According to your description, I couldn’t understand your requirement clearly. which url do you want to rewrite to which url? please give an example of your needs, I will make demo for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple regular expression:

```
<rule name="API Routes" ...>
    <match url="^api/(.*)" />
</rule>
```

Also, remove this part:  `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />`